# SVN Does not recognize created structure

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, svnadmin

I am moving 100+ repos to the new server. I wrote a script to walk the source structure and dump the back up in to the target backup directory. I now have a mirror folder structure with dump files in the appropriate directories.

My next task is to create matching structure on the new server and load all the dumps in to appropriate folders.

My SVN root path is D:\rootpath

The issue i am running into is this: I am creating a folder @ D:\rootpath\folder1\folder 2.    The load of dump should go to folder 2. The load works ok, but SVN does not see the repo that got loaded. However, if I load it to folder1, SVN sees it ok.

How can i get the repo show up when i load it in to folder2?

Comment: In most cases you don’t need to dump and load your repositories when you move them to a new server computer. The steps you take and why you take them is unclear.

Comment: What are the steps to move the repos? Can you point to the guide please? This is what i used https://ardalis.com/moving-svn-repositories-to-new-server/

Comment: Please, see *Step 2. Migrate repositories* in the article https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00166/.